Why Spring Boot DevTools has its dependency as spring-boot-devtools and not as spring-boot-starter-devtools?
About Spring Boot for starters exists the Build Systems - Starters section where shows the following tables:

Table 1. Spring Boot application starters
Table 2. Spring Boot production starters
Table 3. Spring Boot technical starters

Where each starter practically is based with the spring-boot-starter-<something> pattern. It because the first one is spring-boot-starter (perhaps It could had been named as spring-boot-starter-core ... well it is other history)
Now exists Developer Tools where its dependency is declared as:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Observe it is spring-boot-devtools and not as spring-boot-starter-devtools. Why this difference? Even more: this starter does not appear in the Spring Boot application starters table and neither in the others too.

I don't think this is a Stackoverflow question, more like a Spring Boot one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues (though the guys from SB are here so they might actually see it). This looks like a design decision.

Even with that - if you create an issue on GitHub - see the "Question" message. That's why I create the question here.

So you probably will need one of their devs to see your question, I would suggest adding the Java (or the specific language you are using SB with) tag to your question as well.

Although chatGPT gave a pretty good answer for it: * starter. * = ready to production application with common functionalities dependencies, such as data-jpa whereas devtools is especifically focused on  developer-specific tools, such as automatic restart, live reload, etc.

Thanks for the feedback ... I though the same about production too, but exists the spring-boot-starter-test too and that is not for production. I hope you see my point. Agree about to wait an answer from the official team

I would say the test one is for unit test of the start production ones, since test scoped dependencies are not packaged it makes sense for it to be tagged as starter-test.
